# I can't append/update dictionary

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm not sure I wrote right thing on title.

This is the temp thing I use:

```
temp = [{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 't0DC75yq28JLfapz2tE0vdFBPbI', 'id': 'UgwDh4nPhgkxFWgKugd4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'te5pWB4MXQOqSyIRLKRfoot3DBE', 'id': 'UgwDh4nPhgkxFWgKugd4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': '04:05 - Game 1\n18:40 - Game 2\n39:18 - Game 3\n.\n.\n.\n53:40 - Game 4', 'textOriginal': '04:05 - Game 1\n18:40 - Game 2\n39:18 - Game 3\n.\n.\n.\n53:40 - Game 4', 'authorDisplayName': 'Call of Duty League', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxOw3lEOR4JJoANzP9SpvxwqbHQFLyKXbodJQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbLIqv9Puhyp9_ZjVtfOy7w', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCbLIqv9Puhyp9_ZjVtfOy7w'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 20, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-24T23:45:09Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-24T23:45:09Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'J6GD9jA9Feu_H5bqDekuqWYxuq8', 'id': 'Ugwlk-A0J6eEj0JX1_d4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'RTLyHxwu6TP3YEpK3uukxuVjvZc', 'id': 'Ugwlk-A0J6eEj0JX1_d4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': "", 'textOriginal': "", 'authorDisplayName': 'ed dupont', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJz7LbTnu9ijG0k9AT0PU8APaPwL6hA5agOvDQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3bpzuvdQvVRqY2_qVK0YPQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC3bpzuvdQvVRqY2_qVK0YPQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T08:30:39Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T08:31:27Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'KbLI1taGpBwa5N1eFTfdHkoEhU8', 'id': 'UgyOsNEsLi8-pyxDOCt4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'j_jIyr7uUZKw1igiFcYxSWH7RKo', 'id': 'UgyOsNEsLi8-pyxDOCt4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'See how far a non bitching teammate gets you? Gotta love Prestinni', 'textOriginal': 'See how far a non bitching teammate gets you? Gotta love Prestinni', 'authorDisplayName': 'Cirdec4', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzg3O6QDkn-MWF-y9ffkTIfYGWuD9ZVCAQJyQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-ChyQTvh1slIK2qtLNdZMQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC-ChyQTvh1slIK2qtLNdZMQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T05:46:36Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T05:46:36Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': '3CO13KdlL867XPDq--qkeCGwk8E', 'id': 'UgyzOZjkN_qCPt8anV54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'hd-hmzfEzI1Nx_tIRnLOZ8GEico', 'id': 'UgyzOZjkN_qCPt8anV54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': '"Nice shots from accuracy"......\nHuh, I sure hope so lol', 'textOriginal': '"Nice shots from accuracy"......\nHuh, I sure hope so lol', 'authorDisplayName': 'Chance Bates', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxhpDZUST6nKyOeRPbD6poP5-iNRcOikpz2Dg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCzfVbzNLZw8Inh-2LnA959w', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCzfVbzNLZw8Inh-2LnA959w'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T05:32:58Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T05:32:58Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': '-UCfMvoReVh9D9aC2Q2eA2RfnO8', 'id': 'UgyIWBG8QznZUw3PU0x4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'w24T1f3XcSGWhrIEFxjx54lHfyc', 'id': 'UgyIWBG8QznZUw3PU0x4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': "", 'textOriginal': "", 'authorDisplayName': 'Jaymes Johnson', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzcgM94R0IkXuleHeIL6LbqDqazKuqfWpIv=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8Fh--z_Cnb8EC2MwDoKefQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC8Fh--z_Cnb8EC2MwDoKefQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T04:00:08Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T04:00:08Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, [{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': '0SjBlnSNrEnRcl3oFeyjGEndxkw', 'id': 'UgxKDSuoYfA0iYpRd-54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'waRfKBANuZEcnM3tKUJK8cxLX6Q', 'id': 'UgxKDSuoYfA0iYpRd-54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Preston really just ties the huntsmen together', 'textOriginal': 'Preston really just ties the huntsmen together', 'authorDisplayName': 'OKG Disbld', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyF7M6h9c9u5izrIls7mFH5lDdVeD-bkTJJjg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXCn8VPxEK8yx5cn1GSXeVg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCXCn8VPxEK8yx5cn1GSXeVg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T03:54:23Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T03:54:23Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'hkgFxd4BtvECVN-R-9Ce_hDzcbY', 'id': 'UgzUS79dqvguTulmg4J4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'j9pEJB2lLa-eW5r9S-MfFWX08TA', 'id': 'UgzUS79dqvguTulmg4J4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'What gaming platform are they playing on?', 'textOriginal': 'What gaming platform are they playing on?', 'authorDisplayName': 'JAY P', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyccqFTGKWWcUnRXfHtpx_Ukfbzgju-_i6pkA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCrG7H4W_Ij1_E1sxD4Kf2WA', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCrG7H4W_Ij1_E1sxD4Kf2WA'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T03:10:25Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T03:10:25Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 1, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'KhWbq9mJqY5MUQrvOe83IuCenqw', 'id': 'UgwtHBN2fhLenQb2kgB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'BUM6Fvh0tCm1VgPkyis9KlVXcSw', 'id': 'UgwtHBN2fhLenQb2kgB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Please have the stats up more then the faces when you go back and forth', 'textOriginal': 'Please have the stats up more then the faces when you go back and forth', 'authorDisplayName': 'jakemx4', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzptrmxOVLuB6vZj-zClGeJkBoRAOdfv8b27Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVcM99AEcWAyQIMCb5nAPUg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCVcM99AEcWAyQIMCb5nAPUg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 1, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:49:12Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:49:12Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'Ovks4fvIQeHkahWKCe3VXbv59jY', 'id': 'UgxZwIudfutZ2o1LZnp4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': '0EvHJu2i77LFc2-oFbkq0GOhDyE', 'id': 'UgxZwIudfutZ2o1LZnp4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'That t.j Semtex part reminds me of that clip, "tell me when to throw my grenade battle buddy"', 'textOriginal': 'That t.j Semtex part reminds me of that clip, "tell me when to throw my grenade battle buddy"', 'authorDisplayName': 'Ryan Donnelly', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzKwvS5ntOGD-HFlg5cn-M9uHSUpHhw4BmWmw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCe_OzfPnu-cO-2IlVNfB8VA', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCe_OzfPnu-cO-2IlVNfB8VA'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 6, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:41:16Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:41:16Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'bgPxCBDvEBhkZ0farLvUck7ypKY', 'id': 'Ugx2YNnRr3dSSl1V2OV4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': '4PrNxpTj_9liHanxnd_crYouIxM', 'id': 'Ugx2YNnRr3dSSl1V2OV4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': '', 'authorDisplayName': 'maxamillion beckett', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwedihMYkpiuerMyRU47p7Bfuu08ZlF5Haszw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBixB60sGhFwhcXC3nMLo9g', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCBixB60sGhFwhcXC3nMLo9g'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 8, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:41:09Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:41:09Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}], [{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'ya1ezB7Bgt2BiyBe2CY2lufi8BI', 'id': 'UgzvKcfbwGqb2mIWGhl4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'EpFQIF1cIW6ARE7eyPtTY1tbFro', 'id': 'UgzvKcfbwGqb2mIWGhl4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': "", 'authorDisplayName': 'Kaoukabi Jaouad', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzpCZCHBPukYMlwd_1xw9_DvHULCFFErVndxg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC43P7a8ZyWf-gHwfAOK1Ybg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC43P7a8ZyWf-gHwfAOK1Ybg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 3, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:30:31Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:30:31Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'P0OqQdqil06ajanxEPSmRSfGV6M', 'id': 'Ugz-KXSab012wx7xx0F4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': '4ixLRKJ1-hUetfdZ_oXtdST6luI', 'id': 'Ugz-KXSab012wx7xx0F4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'The twins are feasting....ya love to see it.', 'textOriginal': 'The twins are feasting....ya love to see it.', 'authorDisplayName': 'Sean Cunningham', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwIJTzeM0YKTMoFmHarpx-cSyxuVX1sBmQteA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCF0N_9d0oaifOyRmTXZClqg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCF0N_9d0oaifOyRmTXZClqg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 6, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:13:02Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:13:02Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': '_7_zMHscyU5G_DdxZjlGJRv3p0A', 'id': 'UgylQ9a3Ghq8lWLZK5V4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': '85bermA0rZo0pyjZrKHh-hSW1LU', 'id': 'UgylQ9a3Ghq8lWLZK5V4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Damn, no one gave the huntsman a run for their money..\n Easiest dub!', 'textOriginal': 'Damn, no one gave the huntsman a run for their money..\n Easiest dub!', 'authorDisplayName': 'Tobias Ketteringham', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJznscJta-DmM-wai5HHBAjBWRur_ZoKsSUWww=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCHnkun4alZxMCGR-DAiIrTg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCHnkun4alZxMCGR-DAiIrTg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 3, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:11:04Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:11:04Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'J34nt0dUrjLsBx7sNz51SLwPenU', 'id': 'UgzKy1V9nFdM93w2hj54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'mbkQVDODSx1yb2EcvBV6G0t_61U', 'id': 'UgzKy1V9nFdM93w2hj54AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'How many times have sl lost in semis\n\nAnd NYXL is doing the same\n\n\nI FUCKING HATE THIS NY CURSE', 'textOriginal': 'How many times have sl lost in semis\n\nAnd NYXL is doing the same\n\n\nI FUCKING HATE THIS NY CURSE', 'authorDisplayName': 'Matteo Molina', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwhUR91Y9omLqKfVkYgPsdjNaRbeYrQgPDqUg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSFbcitJBj6LxAMXFs8LaXQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCSFbcitJBj6LxAMXFs8LaXQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:05:30Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:05:30Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'LlBj2zE6kPIXfQJd-UfN7qsY-QE', 'id': 'UgzoNFmOtfzcsmRVred4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'uCXPI0gNSEL-Nrfr3CnwhO6xvuY', 'id': 'UgzoNFmOtfzcsmRVred4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'you don’t even need to listen to Scump shout “let’s go BABY”  you know he’s saying that after a 1v2', 'textOriginal': 'you don’t even need to listen to Scump shout “let’s go BABY”  you know he’s saying that after a 1v2', 'authorDisplayName': 'Reece Malone', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJzeHsFx6Xdfk434EppSRNmCzFn84TW4Zp_sKg=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1GzmmFIL_5s-p1DRzEQv1g', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC1GzmmFIL_5s-p1DRzEQv1g'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 33, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T01:04:02Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T01:04:02Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}], [{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'vbamHwwqWwkSsqut084SrRtNMDM', 'id': 'UgxL-3kDqIv1epnS4PB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'gDuu4sF87r78cdVwo2zLhm6yjDM', 'id': 'UgxL-3kDqIv1epnS4PB4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Prestinni literally makes huntsmen SND better without a question ', 'textOriginal': 'Prestinni literally makes huntsmen SND better without a question ', 'authorDisplayName': 'Tommy -_-', 'authorProfileImageUrl': '', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeMNWF-9HCyWivL20cELCjg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCeMNWF-9HCyWivL20cELCjg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 32, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:59:06Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:59:06Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 4, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'So4LRmQs6vetg4JTvZHRv2elcrU', 'id': 'Ugy6tjmKfv0WxVTGSTN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'x4mizZXasOOb4Y7aGP9DpGeWt38', 'id': 'Ugy6tjmKfv0WxVTGSTN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Go scump', 'textOriginal': 'Go scump', 'authorDisplayName': 'DEMONIK COPWATCH', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxrz7k1lRERS51Ch5Wb9BvNQuzN4TeD0eSH6Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVBUGDhfAfmIn6BGpp9SWCw', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCVBUGDhfAfmIn6BGpp9SWCw'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 1, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:55:11Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:55:11Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'lNjEYKV4sFu7Hzn4wVZZjk5PPgo', 'id': 'UgyWRoXYwI_a2hSvSFp4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'D1Hh26W2CGc9Iy7Dp7tJqDJDDvg', 'id': 'UgyWRoXYwI_a2hSvSFp4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'The fact that chicago are breaking hardpoint and stealing spawns are something we havent really seen', 'textOriginal': 'The fact that chicago are breaking hardpoint and stealing spawns are something we havent really seen', 'authorDisplayName': 'Tommy -_-', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyR0lU2d8eM6MjC5P_1PN7E8dytCIYQaCuuDw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeMNWF-9HCyWivL20cELCjg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCeMNWF-9HCyWivL20cELCjg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 17, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:40:25Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:40:25Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'bAwMFPz0dv9f5oTFZHEsyaTFIjE', 'id': 'UgxE0CdDB4CZYBJ3XIN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'Gw5TAAPOxJO7E_hshbYHDwIT6rU', 'id': 'UgxE0CdDB4CZYBJ3XIN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'King scump is back, playing warzone is really improving his tactical instincts and making him an overall better player again', 'textOriginal': 'King scump is back, playing warzone is really improving his tactical instincts and making him an overall better player again', 'authorDisplayName': 'Barbarian My last stand', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxHB49JfKFbRtZvDTrXPJZKv3xhxWPeNXxEKA=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCj8RN6oIfJ8uxO2pLqu2ZkQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCj8RN6oIfJ8uxO2pLqu2ZkQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:38:55Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:38:55Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 1, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'jkoiPGVOyi5_xM23k3GydRdNRbY', 'id': 'UgwAhtZIv3n4oG9e7jx4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'lwoMJ61jUWGYNHSkmaBRUEzXN54', 'id': 'UgwAhtZIv3n4oG9e7jx4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Damn man. Focus and regain Kings.  We’ll get that dub next time.  One better hold and one better rotation in both hardpoints and we’d have won this 3-1.  Kill em next time NYSL!!!!', 'textOriginal': '', 'authorDisplayName': 'GO1 JR', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwQ8aNGhc9YDLruVsKiOfs821_uShxlJUtP7Q=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCX3u88Zsgeu2L8bfvUisS0A', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCX3u88Zsgeu2L8bfvUisS0A'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 3, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:31:05Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:31:05Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 16, 'isPublic': True}}], [{'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'Uki5Ts3n6CUMAXJqWlU3hQHqhNc', 'id': 'UgyMqmldokGVzXq_Weh4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'K9cvb8m4WO4Y0CY6T7LNeL6yBvs', 'id': 'UgyMqmldokGVzXq_Weh4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'Chicago back on top :)', 'textOriginal': 'Chicago back on top :)', 'authorDisplayName': 'Hanna Naegeli', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJxG26RmChtOcYeD4tDquHM7CyZaaAyRgYXGNw=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_ILDK47TpBrnpgR5iTQYwA', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UC_ILDK47TpBrnpgR5iTQYwA'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 2, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:27:38Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:27:38Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'tuWgdEZUAhMI7QyIRHo2WRySQ8M', 'id': 'UgwV1lbd4r0vKvw_XU94AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'SWE3PhY7eeBbnS3sDMQkHpwAXVQ', 'id': 'UgwV1lbd4r0vKvw_XU94AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'loved it', 'textOriginal': 'loved it', 'authorDisplayName': 'Koral', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyjJG1lpphfMILHelRnq7bnoHFJq2YcXOya_g=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCU7_5GsKckyoxLDiGm4k5vQ', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCU7_5GsKckyoxLDiGm4k5vQ'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 0, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:24:26Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:24:26Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'yeFtCjrTo2mo_jTlBSOkObwMpVk', 'id': 'Ugwk2R6gpC3dVuD465Z4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'rVRFlxORoyl4p-qfkT_roUhlpDI', 'id': 'Ugwk2R6gpC3dVuD465Z4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': "Crazy how much better Chicago's hardpoints look. They rotated to perfection.", 'textOriginal': "Crazy how much better Chicago's hardpoints look. They rotated to perfection.", 'authorDisplayName': 'Sports Fan_91', 'authorProfileImageUrl': '', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCIhSBX9r0sbdgIFs2swBSgA', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCIhSBX9r0sbdgIFs2swBSgA'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 30, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:23:37Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:23:37Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'T', 'video_channel': ''}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'AHdvjPclIe1t2E8RVaQrIBqFqsk', 'id': 'Ugw3YVPFxryr5_QqYGN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'VTXwExVzLW_5DNMcZJdNIzWV8Ds', 'id': 'Ugw3YVPFxryr5_QqYGN4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': 'I see lottie i watch', 'textOriginal': 'I see lottie i watch', 'authorDisplayName': 'My two bæs', 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJz4I9kOB8iYjsW5RE9LrNjctNT-sBfst3zCew=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr-J-2AaViMgsVgeZLRtmpg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCr-J-2AaViMgsVgeZLRtmpg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 1, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:20:39Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:20:39Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': 'The eighth home series of the 2020 Call of Duty League season is live on May 22, 23, and 24 on YouTube Gaming. The Seattle Surge are virtually hosting the ...', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}, {'kind': 'youtube#commentThread', 'etag': 'y37zyvJLDL52UR6_RKcnz3SR2Yg', 'id': 'Ugw2aIG_Vq_ZsCdRTGx4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'topLevelComment': {'kind': 'youtube#comment', 'etag': 'j-NgPL49a8z_EezGyELuBOSj3_Q', 'id': 'Ugw2aIG_Vq_ZsCdRTGx4AaABAg', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'NRl-N8uByHY', 'textDisplay': '', 'textOriginal': '', 'authorDisplayName': "LET'S GO HUNTSMEN", 'authorProfileImageUrl': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJyucfyf78MT4_FnmOs3i-HP7hCG-DDTZFVCyQ=s48-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo', 'authorChannelUrl': 'http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCi7CB0b-MAhl2l-rNIBqgDg', 'authorChannelId': {'value': 'UCi7CB0b-MAhl2l-rNIBqgDg'}, 'canRate': True, 'viewerRating': 'none', 'likeCount': 7, 'publishedAt': '2020-05-25T00:15:52Z', 'updatedAt': '2020-05-25T00:25:10Z', 'video_Title': 'Semi-Final B | New York Subliners vs Chicago Huntsmen | Seattle Surge Home Series | Day 3', 'video_desc': '', 'video_channel': 'Call of Duty League'}}, 'canReply': True, 'totalReplyCount': 0, 'isPublic': True}}]]
```

and I tried this and got the output without an error

```
z = []
z.append(temp[0]["snippet"])
```

So it seems I can use loop for this so I tried this:

```
for x in range(len(temp)):
    z.append(temp[x]["snippet"])

for x in temp:
    z.append(x["snippet"])
```

and I got an error as this:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I don't understand what went wrong. It seems both codes are perfectly same code except the loop part. I browsed about nested dictionary, but couldn't find the answer.

Can anyone helps me the difference?
My goal is to extract each elements' ["snippet"]["topLevelComment"]["snippet"]. and make it 
 xlsx file with pandas. As you already noticed, I'm not familiar with dictionary. So if there  is any good way to extract those things, please enlighten me.

Thank you in advance brilliant advisors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
for x in temp:
    print(type(x))
```

produces this

```
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'dict'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

So it seems that some elements in `temp` are dictionaries and some are lists. The error comes from trying to access `x["snippet"]` for those elements `x` in `temp` that are lists.

Comment: Oh, genius! Couldn't think of there can be mixed ones. I should check what went wrong in there. Thanks for a big time Heike. :)